# Do you really believe in -450 degree Celsius?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

There's a nonsense in this  [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/32650/9134), simply copied from the linked document. On sites like SO, it'd have been fixed rather immediately, here a fruitless discussion in comments started, so I thought, it's my turn. But [my edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13814) was rejected.

I'm not whining about it, I just want it to get fixed. It ain't no rocket science, is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it :)

I'm surprised your edit was rejected, but if in doubt you can always post in meta (like you have) or even just mention it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat).

Comment: "I'm surprised your edit was rejected" well the user doing it provided some explanations: keeping the original source verbatim. But AFAIC this isn't a correct approach, even if the correction might be indicated (e.g. with a note indicating that the typo was corrected). The original source may disappear and we don't want to go propagating mistakes.

Comment: I agree with @bilbo_pingouin's above comment. (I actually pondered fixing it while I was LaTeX-ifying the table, but decided to leave the error where it was to clearly isolate the purely presentational changes from any changes to the content of the answer, then left a comment mentioning it.)

Comment: There are mechanisms for noting errors in quoted material, like [sic] and [typo corrected —Ed] in-line, “emphasis mine” before the quote block, or just citing a copy that doesn't contain the error.

Answer (score 0):

My main excuse is that I'm new here and I'm not yet used to the conventions on such things. It was a bit of a fire and forget answer, I didn't actually check the rest of the values on there were correct, just that they were within the ranges I expected.